# SQL autoincrement value based on column

Tags: sql, sql-server, row, rank, dense-rank

I have case in which I want same autoincrement value in new created column for same business code
I have tried below but I am not getting expected result

```
select *
    , rank() over (partition by business_code order by ID)
from table
```

I am getting same same value in ID column for all business code which is not desired result.

My Output

[image: Id businesscode NewColumn 1 eng 1 2 mkr 1 3 eng 2 4 fin 1 5 mkr 2]

Expected Output

[image: Id businesscode NewColumn 1 eng 1 2 mkr 2 3 eng 1 4 fin 3 5 mkr 2]

Comment: Show us your sample data, actual results and desired results.

Comment: Seeing as the results returned for the ID column can only be part of the SELECT * in this example I don't think the issue is in your usage of RANK(). It might well be that in your simplification of the rest of your code you've accidentally cut out something that we need to know

Comment: added sample data

Comment: @DaleK added sample data

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Id 3 is the second instance of business code "eng" so it should have rank 2, same for Id 5 being the second instance of "mkr". Is what you're trying to do is assign an ID based on BusinessCode?

Comment: Can you explain your expected results here? They aren't what I, and I suspect others, expect, so you need to explain the logic behind it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT id
      ,business_code
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY m) NewColumn
FROM (SELECT id
            ,business_code
            ,MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY business_code) m
      FROM myTable) d
```

An explanation how it works: because of provided data i thought to get the minimum id of each business_code first. And as second step ranking that minimum id by value.

Comment: this is a great solution but does assume that IDs are unique (which I hope they are given the name...)

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)), a.*
from Table a;
```

Comment: I have tried but I am not getting expected output